# In MCPE v.0.15.2 can you trade with villagers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to trade with villagers in version 0.15.2? I have tried but I just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading), it looks like trading only works on PC and Console, but not Pocket Edition.

> The trading system is a gameplay mechanic that allows players to trade emeralds for items (and vice-versa) with villagers. *Trading is not available in Pocket Edition.*